# feathers js get custom attribute value

Tags: javascript, feathers-sequelize

I'm first time using feathers and Sequelize.
I want ask something for the example I have data user

```
name: 'user b',
email:'userb@mail.com',
createdAt:'2022-02-02',
updatedAt: '2022-02-02',
}
```

my expected return

```
name: 'user b',
email: 'userb@mail.com',
}
```

but I got all data user b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `after` hook to delete the properties that you don't want to get.
Or you can use the [feathers.js common querying](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/databases/querying.html#equality) to deselect the specific fields and querying is the better approach.

Still, if you want to use the hooks, here is the code example:

```
after: {
    get: [ (context) => {
        delete context.result.data.fieldName;
    }
}
```